# How to use out parameter in oracleprepared statment

Tags: java, oracle

I have a procedure which has two output parameters and one object as an input parameter. I have to provide the input parameter as an ARRAY(SQL Array) but I have no idea how deal with the output parameters.

```
OraclePreparedStatement pstmt =
  (OraclePreparedStatement)conn.prepareStatement(
      "call stg_core.insert_flexi_gl_response(?,?,?)");
pstmt.registerReturnParameter(1, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
pstmt.setARRAY( 3, array_to_pass );
```

I am getting a compilation error at `OracleTypes.VARCHAR`. I have tried importing all the option provided by eclipse but nothing is working.

I am getting the error `OracleTypes cannot be resolved to a variable`.
Kindly provide me any solution or workaround.

Comment: I don't know much about Java, so only guessing (based on some .NET experience) ... A proper namespace (for the `OracleTypes`) missing?

Comment: You added `import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes` and still get the same error? How about fully specifying `oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR` in the call instead? I think you want an `OracleCallableStatement` here though really, with `registerOutParameter()`. What you have is for the DML `returning` clause.